# Android Broadcast принимающий сообщения от Activity

Tags: java, android, android-service, broadcast-receiver

Добрый день. Подскажите решение, не удается зарегистрировать `BroadcastReceiver` внутри `IntentService` и передать сообщение из `Activity`.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
        intent.putExtra("HighScore", 1000);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);
    }

    public void testClick(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class));
    }
}
```

IntentService

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.Broadcast");
        receiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните что не получилось. Код выглядит верным. Как вы определили, что он не работает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В отладке не вызывается onReceive

Comment: @Proxyma скажите что вы этим хотите добиться, код по логике очень не понятный... зачем вам broadcastreceiver, если вы можете это сделать и в IntentService?

Comment: @Lex Hobbit В итоге в Service будет Socket, по которому будут идти сообщения, я хочу управлять сообщениями из Activity и для этого и нужна связь с сервисом, приведенный код лишь для демонстрации, далее в onReceive я буду вызывать методы сервиса(передам в ресивер контекст сервиса).

Comment: @Proxyma Он создает новый поток для своей работы. Затем берет все Intent пришедшие ему в onStartCommand и отправляет их на обработку в этот поток. Как именно обрабатываются Intent – зависит от нас, т.к. мы сами кодим это в методе onHandleIntent.

Т.е. приложение сыпет в сервис вызовами startService, в которых передает Intent-ы. IntentService принимает эти вызовы в onStartCommand, берет Intent-ы и отправляет их в очередь на обработку. И далее они поочередно обрабатываются в отдельном потоке методом onHandleIntent. Когда последний Intent из очереди обработан, сервис сам завершает свою работу.

Comment: @Proxyma это я к тому, что вам не нужен BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, что-то я не понял, это я могу сколько раз хочу стартить сервис и сокет открытый внутри не рухнет?

Comment: @Proxyma если использовать IntentService, то да. Вообще Intent Service очень удобно использовать при последовательном выполнение задач, которые необходимо вынести из UI-потока. Только его нужно правильно готовить и почитайте про LifeCycle у IntentService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регистрацию ресивера надо сажать в `onCreate()` и вызывать `unregisterReceiver()` в `onDestroy()` сервиса.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что `SendBroadcast` вызывается до регистрации ресивера. В таком случае действительно, лучше сделать регистрацию `onCreate` либо в манифесте.